# How to remove elements in one list according to the conditions on corresponding elements of another list?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists that have the same length, lstA, lstB, I want to remove elements that are not good based on some conditions, but at the meaning time, I also want to remove the elements in lstB that have the same position with the unwanted one in lstA. like below:

```
lstA = ['good','good2', '']
lstB = [1,2,3]
```

**I want '' in lstA and 3 in lstB removed:**

```
results:
lstA = ['good','good2']
lstB = [1,2]
```

Currently, I am doing this:

```
lstB = [lstB[i] for i in range(len(lstB)) if lstA[i] != '']
lstA = [st for st in lstA if st != '']
```

**Want a more elegant and pythonic way of doing this**

Comment: as your code is actually working; the correct site to post questions like this would be [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sure, thanks, I will go